# How to get image size from URL in java

Tags: java, size

I want to get the image size from the URL.
My source is working locally but aws Ubuntu server will return -1.
What's the problem?

`URL url=new URL("https://www.bithumb.com/resources/img/comm/sp_coin.png?v=180510");`

`int image_size = url.openConnection().getContentLength();`

`System.out.println("mage size:: "+image_size);`

Answer (score 0):

If the server doesn't respond with a valid `Content-Length` header, `getContentLength` returns `-1`. As an alternative, you can always get the size of the returned data:

```
size = IOUtils.toByteArray(url.openStream()).length;
```

Using Apahe commons IO [`IOUtils`](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/javadocs/api-release/index.html?org/apache/commons/io/IOUtils.html).

Answer (score 0):

> What's the problem?

Difficult to say.  However, ultimately it is up to the implementation of the web service (not Ubuntu or AWS) to include a content length in the response.

So if you want to find out *why* (and fix it) you need to examine the implementation of the (your?) web service, and how it is creating the responses.

As @jspcal points out, you can work around the problem.  But in order to do that you would need to (at least) read the entire image from the response data stream.   Whether this is a viable / efficient solution depends how / when you intend to use the content length.